# Regex Expression to match X or more characters until first forward slash

Tags: regex, string, string-length

Trying to check a string like this:

```
Product Title Here / Something / Something else
```

I want to isolate the first string before the first `/` and then see how long it is and only match if it is longer than 10 characters (including spaces).

So split the string by / and then see if it can iterate 10 or more times? Sorry I am new at Regex!

My failed attempt:

```
.+?(?=\/){10,}
```

So it should isolate "Product Title Here" and return match if that is longer than 10 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
^[^/]{10,}
```

`[^/]` matches anything except `/`, and `{10,}` requires it to be at least 10 characters long.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/OYahmr/1)

Comment: I tried to test this in Regex101.com and it didn't come back as a match. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I've added a link showing it works. Depending on the flavor you select, you may need to escape `/`.

Comment: Will this version that you are using work in Google Analytics expressions?

Comment: If you're using JavaScript you have to escape `/` because it's the same as the RegExp delimiter.

Comment: I checked the RE2 documentation and I think it should work. https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax